# Scrollable div inside section of Fullpage.js doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullpage.js, slimscroll

I want to have a scrollable div inside a section of fullpage.js but when I include `scrollOverflow: true` then I get this error: `Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of undefined.`

The scrollOverflow library is included:

http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/1827/

I wonder what am I missing:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'orange', '#C0C0C0', '#ADD8E6'],
    scrollOverflow: true
});
$('.fp-scrollable').slimScroll({
    alwaysVisible: true,
    color: 'black',
    size: '10px',
    allowPageScroll: true,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup seems to be not what `jquery.fullPage.js` expects. It expects an element with the class `fp-scrollable` to have children, which is not the case in your jsfiddle.

If you move the class so that

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="test fp-scrollable">
    ...
```

becomes

```
<div class="section fp-scrollable">
    <div class="test">
    ...
```

you'll see it working. Maybe this is not the markup you want to end up with, maybe you want to further nest `.test` instead, but regardless this gives you an idea on how to tackle the error.

Comment: I don't know why you got downvoted but you are right. thanks

Comment: Don't know either. You're welcome, glad this helped you.

Comment: I'm the creator of fullPage.js and I down-voted it. `fp-scrollable` is an internal class used by fullPage.js and should not be added by developers. 
When using `scrollOverflow:true`, fullPage.js will add the required class wherever it needs it.
Additionally, he is calling `slimScroll()`, which makes no sense anymore because fullPage.js doesn't use slimScroll but iScroll.js.
And if he just want a scrollable div, he might as well just use `normalScrollElements`. Oh... and the proposed solution [doesn't work anyways](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/1831/).

Comment: @Alvaro can you please suggest the correct solution, I have one more query I have created 11 sections using this fullpage.js but  on switching from default to second it skips 2nd and land on 3rd section

Comment: @RakhiPrajapati see my answer  for fullpag.js version 2 below https://stackoverflow.com/a/43174091/1081396

Answer (score 3):

You just need to use `scrollOverflow:true` and include the `scrolloverflow.min.js` file as detailed in [the fullPage.js docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js).

> scrollOverflow: (default false) (not compatible with IE 8) defines whether or not to create a scroll for the section/slide in case its content is bigger than the height of it. When set to true, your content will be wrapped by the plugin. Consider using delegation or load your other scripts in the afterRender callback. In case of setting it to true, it requires the vendor library scrolloverflow.min.js and it should be loaded before the fullPage.js plugin. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/scrolloverflow.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
```

You have an example available in [the examples folder in fullPage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/examples/scrollOverflow.html)

For fullPage.js version 3 it would almost be identical:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/scrolloverflow.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fullpage.js"></script>
```

Comment: Who else can answer it better than the creator himself! :D

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that you need to do is to assign some kind of selector on the area that you want to be able to scroll inside fullpage section for example

`<div id="scroll-area">Some long scrollable content</div>`

After that just add an option to fullpage.js

```
normalScrollElements: '#scroll-area'
```

And that’s all you have area that can be scrolled inside fullpage.js section

Answer (score -1):

Your issue comes from `scrollOverflow: true` . It might mean your are missing [slimScroll](https://plugins.jquery.com/slimScroll/) . You've got full details [here](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20scrollHeight%20).

Calling something on unknown means the object you need haven't been defined yet at usage time. It might be wise to use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ /*code*/ });
```

To avoid problems. Although it doesn't fix your current issue.

**-- EDIT bcs of -1
=> Still proud of my anser. #EOF**

Comment: You were likely downvoted by Alvaro, the creator of fullpage.js. and the reason is obviously because you suggested using slimScroll even though fullpage uses iScroll. 

Look at the comments on the accepted answer.